# Liferay document checkout/in permission

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, administration, document-library, document-management

I am using **Liferay 6.2 EE sp7 Tomcat bundle on Linux**.

We have a use case for the normal regular users to upload, check in and out documents from the document and media portlet.

I see the Checkout and Check in options when I am logged in as a administrator but not as a regular user who is a site member with default permissions.

**Question:**
Is there a way to turn on the Check out/in options for the regular users either with configuration via properties file or permssions etc.?

**Steps I took:**

As an administrator:

- Create a site with private pages only.
- create a private page and add document and media portlet and a document and media display portlet to the page.
- create a folder in the site.
- upload couple of documents to the new folder.
- You will be able to see the checkout option after clicking on the document you just uploaded in either of the portlets (see screen shot)
  [image]
- Add a regular user(non admin)  and make a site member of the private site.

**In a different browser:**

- login as the regular user and navigate the private page/site created above.
- click into the folder/file uploaded above.
- the Check out option is not present.

I have researched portal properties, portlet permissions and the configuration option of the portlets above. I don't see anything that is hopeful or that works.

Please let me know if there is a work around or configuration I need to do turn this on.

Thanks a lot for the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked it on `liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5`, but I think it can be similar in your version. You can set this permissions for "regular user" role (I set it for Power User role):

```
Documents and Media Display > Document: Override Checkout 
Documents and Media Display > Document: Update
```

"Override Checkout" permission requires "Update" permission.

After this checkout/checkin options are available for my non-admin user.

Comment: Thanks @glw. For now I do not need the Override Checkout option. I tried just the "Update" and it works fine.